# While over Associative Array on PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

I worked two hours to solve it but I need you mates. I need to make an array with which I get from db. Lets take a look at:

```
$conn_msg_attach = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_msg_attach WHERE msg_ID = '$msgID'");
while($get_msg_attach = mysql_fetch_array($conn_msg_attach)) {

$msg_attach_path = $get_msg_attach['msg_filepath'];
$msg_attach_fullpath = '../../../files/task_files/'.$msg_attach_path;

$files = array($msg_attach_path => $msg_attach_fullpath);
}
```

With above code I need to make is:

```
$files = array(
      'something.ttf' => '../../../files/task_files/something.ttf',
      'dsc.jpg' => '../../../files/task_files/dsc.jpg', 
      'hope.pdf' => '../../../files/task_files/hope.pdf'
);
```

It's not working exactly. Connected with question: [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48971809/6226001)
file.zip will be invalid. I couldn't find what the problem is.

I changed my point of view and write below code. But still get the error "ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object". puff!!

```
$zipname = 'task.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

$conn_msg_attach = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_msg_attach WHERE msg_ID = '$msgID'");
while($get_msg_attach = mysql_fetch_array($conn_msg_attach)) {

    $msg_attach_path = $get_msg_attach['msg_filepath'];
    $msg_attach_fullpath = '../../../files/task_files/'.$msg_attach_path;

$zip->addFile($msg_attach_fullpath, $msg_attach_path);

}

$zip->close();
```

Thank you for any help.

**FINAL SOLUTION FOR THE QUESTION:**

```
$msgID = $_GET['msgID'];
$zipname = 'task.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

$conn_msg_attach = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM task_msg_attach WHERE msg_ID = '$msgID'");
while($get_msg_attach = mysql_fetch_array($conn_msg_attach)) {

    $msg_attach_path = $get_msg_attach['msg_filepath'];
    $msg_attach_fullpath = '../../../files/task_files/'.$msg_attach_path;

$zip->addFile($msg_attach_fullpath, $msg_attach_path);

}

$zip->close();

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
ob_clean();
readfile($zipname);
ob_flush();
```

Comment: `$files[] = array( ...` ? oh and mysql -- just stop using that

Comment: Please note the `mysql_` constructor has been [**deprecated since 2013 (in PHP 5.5)**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), and is [**removed in PHP 7 (released in 2015)**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7#extmysql). Please consider switching to either [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), ensuring that you also use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) :)

Comment: My answer is updated for your updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UPDATED as question was updated

- Your path structure is wrong. don't use `../` but use an [absolute file path](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm#GUID-5118AC85-57E4-4027-AC24-FB6E99FADEFF).
- What does your [PHP Error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel) say?
- Also you don't seem to be actually [following Viney's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48973625/3536236) and using `$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);`

---

Your Syntax is wrong:

```
$files = array($msg_attach_path => $msg_attach_fullpath);
```

Here you are **setting** the value each iteration, instead of ***adding to*** the value that already was set last iteration.

You want to build an array of values, called `files`, each iteration of the loop you want to *add one more row to the array* rather than set a new array. 
So:

```
$files[] = array($msg_attach_path => $msg_attach_fullpath);
```

This adds a new row to the `$files` array each time it's called. This can also be rewritten as:

```
$files[]['$msg_attach_path'] = $msg_attach_fullpath;
```

result:

> $files[0] = array(
>          'something.ttf' => '../../../files/task_files/something.ttf');
>      $files[1] = array(
>         'dsc.jpg' => '../../../files/task_files/dsc.jpg');
>      $files[2] = array(
>         'hope.pdf' => '../../../files/task_files/hope.pdf');
>   etc.

(*This can also be further tidied up and improved depending on your exact criteria*) .

- ## [Stop using `mysql_` PHP functions. *Use `MySQLi_` at the very least*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891443/when-should-i-use-mysqli-instead-of-mysql).

Comment: see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727746/how-do-i-fill-an-array-inside-a-while-loop-and-get-new-scope-each-iteration)

Comment: Thank you Martin. I will try the solution. I started my project two years ago. So, I need to continue on php 5. I started to learn codeignitor but structure of php 7 is more complicated for me to change my project base at this time.

Comment: @Pecado PHP5.6 is fine, for now. It can use `PDO` and `MySQLi` without any problems. `:-)`

Comment: I couldn't success :( I changed my point of view and wrote the following code. It also get "ZipArchive::addFile(): Invalid or uninitialized Zip object in" error. I enter the code on question post.

Comment: Succeed! All problem was I forgot to changed row :( $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE); thank u Martin for your support. :) I add final code to my question post to  make use of.